# Simple Union type fails to type check in MyPy

Tags: python, mypy

The following simple type check fails in MyPy.

```py
from typing import Dict, Union

A = Dict[str, Union[str, Dict[str, str]]]
B = Union[A, Dict[str, str]]

example: B = {"x": {"y": "z"}}
```

This results in an error message when checked with MyPy:

```
Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Dict[str, Dict[str, str]]", variable has type "Union[Dict[str, Union[str, Dict[str, str]]], Dict[str, str]]")  [assignment]mypy(error)
```

I cannot see any problem here. There are no errors if I type `example` as `A` instead of `B`, and B is simply a union that includes A, so it's hard not to think that this is a bug in MyPy. But I wanted to check here first in case I was missing something obvious.

Comment: `{"x": {"y": "z"}}` is a `dict[str, dict[str, str]]`, you have defined `B` as a possible `dict[str, str]` which doesn't cover what you are attempting to set `example` as.

Comment: @VoidTwo sounds weird: from your logic `x: int | str = 1` should be forbidden as well. Upcasting should never be unsafe. I bet the problem is related to `dict` invariance, `mypy` just fails here for some reason. This bug is worth new issue at [their issue tracker](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues), because `x: T1 | T2 = val` should *always* be allowed where `x: T1 = val` is. Your example passes `pyright` check.

Comment: I suspect this is a variance issue as well. Mypy is probably bending the rules to allow a constant whose inferred type is `dict[A, B]` to be upcast at first assignment to `dict[A, B | C]`, but it can't do that inside a union. I'm betting the reason the first ascription works at all is a subtle trick of mypy

Comment: Interestingly, if you declare `example` to be an `A`, you can then assign `example_b: B = example` with no error.

Comment: I created an issue on the MyPy github issue tracker: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/15323